# Can not apply indexing with[] to an expression of type method group."

Tags: c#, itext

I am working with iTextSharp C#.net and dealing with RenderText method but I am getting **"Can not apply indexing with[] to an expression of type method group."** error in the below **"Chunk Location"** section. Here is my code:

```
public virtual void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            LineSegment segment = renderInfo.GetBaseline();
            TextChunk location = new TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), segment.GetStartPoint(), segment.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth());

            **"//Chunk Location:"**
            Debug.Print(renderInfo.GetText());
            location.PosLeft =renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint[Vector.I1])); //In the below four lines getting the error.
            location.PosRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint[Vector.I1];
            location.PosBottom = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint[Vector.I2];
            location.PosTop = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint[Vector.I2];

            //Chunk Font Size: (Height)
            location.curFontSize = location.PosTop - segment.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I2];
            //Use Font name  and Size as Key in the SortedList
            string StrKey = renderInfo.GetFont().PostscriptFontName + location.curFontSize.ToString();
            //Add this font to ThisPdfDocFonts SortedList if it's not already present
            if (!ThisPdfDocFonts.ContainsKey(StrKey))
            {
                ThisPdfDocFonts.Add(StrKey, renderInfo.GetFont());
            }
            //Store the SortedList index in this Chunk, so we can get it later
            location.FontIndex = ThisPdfDocFonts.IndexOfKey(StrKey);
            locationalResult.Add(location);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the indexing after the method call.

```
location.PosLeft =renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint()[Vector.I1];
location.PosRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint()[Vector.I1];
location.PosBottom = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint()[Vector.I2];
location.PosTop = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint()[Vector.I2];
```